# PuTTY PSFTP return codes

Tags: sftp, putty

I've been unable to find a list of PuTTY (psftp.exe) exit values or return codes.

The only thing I found is this: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter10.html#errors, but I need the return codes.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For most programs, there isn't generally a lot of informational content in exit codes. If you're trying to automate detailed error handling (why is your question tagged with java and c#?) you may need to parse error messages.

Looking at the [source code](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=blob;f=psftp.c;h=d35b8fa3c305c31321ed3c526e5d11acd810d3d0;hb=HEAD), it appears that it returns 1 if there is a connection error or if it is unable to open a batch file, 2 if a command fails in batch mode, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for getting some of the return codes from the source code. Tectia SFTP has a list of exit values (https://www.ssh.com/manuals/server-zos-user/62/sftpg3.html), so does WinSCP SFTP (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes). That's why I was wondering why I couldn't find a PuTTY list of return values .

Comment: Note that your WinSCP page seems to be a listing of SFTP protocol codes and is not necessarily suitable for automating the WinSCP command itself.

Answer (score 2):

PSFTP has these exit codes:

- 0 - success
- 1 - fatal error
- 2 - command error (when `-be` is not used)

Comment: How do you access these exit codes when running psftp.exe in windows? Is it possible? I run psftp.exe from a windows batch file.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald See [How to check the exit code of the last command in batch file?](https://superuser.com/q/194662/213663)

Comment: Wow ok, I didn't realise IF statements were available inside windows batch files. You live and learn!